# how to make a table with different types

Tags: c++

i need to put some data of different types(int,string)in the same table (knowing  that the structure of the table is **variable**(**rows, columns, the type of the data in the column is variable**))  ,how can i do this in C++

Comment: `std::variant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). The former is type-safe, but only available in C++17 and later.

Comment: or if you want to be creative a struct of multiple std::optional so you can check which of the values is set. Though std::variant is probably your best bet (to check which type is used at runtime use std::variant<T>::index.

Comment: @PepijnKramer That seems like an unnecessarily complex solution, which would also waste memory.

Comment: yeah it is, hence the creative bit and my comment on std::variant :)